# Top to Bottom with coord flip

Tags: r, ggplot2

When using ggplot like this

```
data_frame(diamonds)

ggplot(diamonds,aes(cut)) +
  geom_bar()
```

I get a plot as expected, however when I do this:

```
ggplot(diamonds,aes(cut)) +
  geom_bar() +
  coord_flip()
```

I flip the plot but the new "y" values go from bottom to top, is it possible to flip the coordinate AND have the values going from top to botton? So "fair" would be the top most value, then "good", then "very good"... etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `fct_rev` from `forcats`

```
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(fct_rev(cut))) +
       geom_bar() +
       coord_flip() + 
       xlab('cut')
```

[image]